# How to scroll to the last added item in RecyclerView, when the item have been shuffled using collection

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview, items

since the items in recyclerview have been already shuffled (using Collections.sort(dataList, MainData.Increment);) I cannot use the Id from database or dataList, because it will not correspond to the position of the item in the recyclerview.

recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(??????); How to know the right integer value?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you use Collections.Sort(dataList) that means your repository has the original list, meaning you know the size of the list. If you need to scroll to the last item... it's the list size... Alternatively, you can do `adapter.itemCount` if i correctly recall to know how many items the adapter has.

Comment: can't use that as it gives me the size of the list and scrolls all the way down/up to the top of the recyclerview instead of to the last added item, which for example is somewhere in the middle of the recyclerview (because of the items being sorted )

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"` in your recyclerView in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The way this question is phrased is very unclear exactly what you need.

Let's put it this way:

1. You have a `List<Thing>`.
2. You Sort this `List<Thing>`.
3. You pass this to your REcyclerView's Adapter.
4. You need to add an item, resort the list and then scroll to that item in the RecyclerView.

Nowhere in this *affaire*, the RecyclerView and its adapter have much to say.

You add the item, sort the list, pass it onto the adapter, also find the position in the list (not the adapter, the original list you have just sorted). Since the adapter and your sorted list have the same data, position N in the list, is position N in the adapter.

You can then say adapter.scrollToPosition(N).

What part of this is not working for you?

> it will not correspond to the position of the item in the recyclerview.

Why would this be the case?

If I supply a `list` with 10 items to my adapter. My `list.size` is going to be the same as the `adapter.itemCount`, so item 0 in the adapter, is the same as item 0 in the list, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is my list is let say 1 million items long, when I add 1 million +1 item the itemCount, or list.size always give the highest integer value what will always scroll to the top. But my 1milion +1 item isn't displayed at the top, it  is somewhere in the middle of my long list, and I would like my 1milion +1 item to be visible in the middle of the screen (which only shows a few items at a time at best). If user ads 1milion+1 item it should scroll to it so they can see it, without manually searching through all the item to be able to see it.

Comment: Ok.. that changes things, next time consider mentioning that in your original question :) For this particular use-case, you're going to have to expand your solution a bit; are you using the Pagination library? (at this point, I don't know how to solve this without looking at some code, or experimenting myself). 1mil+ items is a lot, and so if you add something in the middle, I'd expect you have an API (or similar) that can return you the "page" (records) where an item "X" is located. Say you get -10 and +10 items or similar. But I'd have to look at it in action to imagine the solution.